# Object properties are undefined, the object itself shows all the data though

Tags: javascript, object

I'm building an Single Page application for a minor project. I've been trying to save data from API call's to the Movie Database in an object. If i console.log the object, I can see all its properties and values. If I console.log the object.property, it returns 'undefined'. This is the code:

```
(() => {
"use strict"

  /* Saving sections to variables
  --------------------------------------------------------------*/
  const movieList = document.getElementsByClassName('movie_list')[0];
  const movieSingle = document.getElementsByClassName('movie_single')[0];

  /* All standard filters for displaying movies
  --------------------------------------------------------------*/
  const allFilters = {
    trending: 'movie/popular',
    toplist: 'movie/top_rated',
    latest: 'movie/now_playing',
    upcoming: 'movie/upcoming'
  };

  const allData = {};

  /* Initialize app - Get al standard data and save it in object
  --------------------------------------------------------------*/
  const app = {
    init() {
        getData(allFilters.trending, 'popular');
        getData(allFilters.toplist, 'toplist');
        getData(allFilters.latest, 'latest');
        getData(allFilters.upcoming, 'upcoming');

        this.startPage();
    },
    startPage() {
      window.location.hash = "trending";
    }
  }

  /* Function for getting data from the API
  --------------------------------------------------------------*/
  const getData = (filter, key) => {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const apiKey = '?api_key=xxx';
    const getUrl = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${filter}${apiKey}`;

    request.open('GET', getUrl, true);
    request.onload = () => {
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        let data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        data.filter = key;
        cleanData.init(data);
      } else {
        window.location.hash = 'random';
      }
    };
    request.onerror = () => {
      console.error('Error');
    };
    request.send();
  };

  /* Check if the data is list or single, and clean up
  --------------------------------------------------------------*/
  const cleanData = {
    init(originalData) {
      if (!originalData.results) {
        this.single(originalData);
      } else {
        allData[originalData.filter] = originalData;
      }
    },

    list(data) {
      data.results.map(function(el) {
        el.backdrop_path = `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${el.backdrop_path}`;
      });
      let attributes = {
        movie_image: {
          src: function() {
            return this.backdrop_path;
          },
          alt: function() {
            return this.title;
          }
        },
        title_url: {
          href: function() {
            return `#movie/${this.id}/${this.title}`;
          }
        }
      }
      showList(data.results, attributes);
    },

    single(data) {
      data.poster_path = `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${data.poster_path}`;
      data.budget = formatCurrency(data.budget);
      data.revenue = formatCurrency(data.revenue);
      data.runtime = `${(data.runtime / 60).toFixed(1)} uur`;
      data.imdb_id = `http://www.imdb.com/title/${data.imdb_id}`;
      let attributes = {
        movie_image: {
          src: function() {
            return this.poster_path;
          },
          alt: function() {
            return this.title;
          }
        },
        imdb_url: {
          href: function() {
            return this.imdb_id
          }
        },
        similar_url: {
          href: function() {
            return `#movie/${this.id}/${this.title}/similar`
          }
        }
      };
      showSingle(data, attributes);
    }
  };

  const showList = (cleanedData, attributes) => {
    movieList.classList.remove('hidden');
    movieSingle.classList.add('hidden');
    Transparency.render(movieList, cleanedData, attributes);
  };

  const showSingle = (cleanedData, attributes) => {
    movieSingle.classList.remove('hidden');
    movieList.classList.add('hidden');
    Transparency.render(movieSingle, cleanedData, attributes);
  }

const formatCurrency = amount => {
    amount = amount.toFixed(0).replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
      return i && c !== "." && ((a.length - i) % 3 === 0) ? '.' + c : c;
    });
    return `€${amount},-`;
  };

  app.init();

console.log(allData); // Returns object with 4 properties: trending, toplist, latest & upcoming. Each property is filled with 20 results (movies with data) from the API.

console.log(allData.trending) // Returns 'undefined' (each property I've tried).

console.log(allData['trending']) // Returns 'undefined'

Object.keys(allData); // Returns an empty Array []

})();
```

When I use `console.log(allData)` I see 4 properties, all filled with the results from the API. But when i do `console.log(allData.trending)` or `console.log(allData['trending'])` it returns 'Undefined' in the console. Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: what is the output of `Object.keys(allData)` ?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal it returns an empty array

Comment: It seems like the properties are not of the object. I mean, the properties you see on the console are from the prototype.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, should the URL be `/3/${filter}/${apiKey}` without the `/` its like a single param? `${filter}${apiKey}`

Comment: @sabithpocker It looks like that now indeed, the API key, stored in the variable, starts with `?api_key=`, but for this post I've deleted it.

Comment: Where exactly are you doing the `console.log`? I can't find logs in the code. Can you add those to the code sample and put some comments on what you are getting and what you expect to get?

Comment: @sabithpocker I've added them to the bottom of the code

Comment: This is a common pitfall trying to log results from async calls. Let me check for a similar question so that we don't have duplicate questions/answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `app.init()` it fires the `init` and sends the api call(s) to fetch data.

The call to fetch data is Asynchronous, which means it doesn't wait for the response to continue execution. So it goes ahead and executes next lines of code, which are your `console.logs`. At this time the API calls haven't responded with the data, so when you try to access `data.property` it fails as the data is not yet here.

When you do `log(data)` it creates a log of the reference to data, which gets updated in the log when the reference is filled with a value later. To get the value of `data` at that instance and prevent updating later you can try `log(JSON.stringify(data))`. When you do that you get a consistent result, none of your logs work, which is the actual behaviour.

To get your logs work, look into the success/load callback of you A(synchronous)JAX request, log it from there. Or if you constructed `allData` later in `cleanData` then call the logs after `cleanData` function.

So to answer your question, none of your logs should work as it is an asynchronous call. You are getting the `allData` logged due to the way `console.log` works with references that are updated later, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(allData))` to get the actual snapshot of Object

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! :)